# Better environment to develop a Wagtail-based website

Tags: django, docker, wagtail

I'm going to develop a Wagtail-based website in Windows. If Linux is a better production environment, should I use a subsystem for Linux, a virtual machine for Linux, or docker in development?

Comment: I've used a Vagrant/Virtualbox VM and Windows Subsystem for Linux.  Have never used Docker.  I much prefer WSL over Vagrant/Virtualbox.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't or don't want to use Windows Subsystem for Linux, a decent option is running a Linux VM and accessing the VM through a program like Moba Xterm. Inside the VM, you can decide to simply run your app or run it in Docker.

Docker would make it easier to run on other setups if you change your mind or if someone else starts working on it.

Either way, if you enable port-forwarding in your VirtualBox you will be able to access the site on your host machine.